# YSlow recommendations. In IIS, why wouldn't  Enable Content Expiration be checked by default in 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis-6, yslow

i just ran yslow against my website and i had a question around Expiry Headers:  YSlow gave me an : **Grade F on Add Expires headers.   There are 20 static components without a far-future expiration date.**  These are all css or js files.

Right now when i go to IIS (6.0), and go to the http headers tab, Enable Content Expiration is NOT checked. from [reading this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true) it seems like this is the right thing to do as the browser will then cache the content.  So i am confused why yslow is complaining.  Also, it sounds like browsers will cache this data by modified date anyway so is this whole thing meaningless ??

So if setting this is a no brainer, why isn't this the default behavior??

Can someone please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no contradiction here. What you need to do is set content expiration on the **folders which contain static content**. Such as your image, css, and script folders. You can set the content expiration on a folder-basis in IIS and other web servers.

Comment: thanks.  But from what i read, browsers will cache all static content anyway.  Is that correct??

Comment: @ooo. Not true. If a file has no content expiration or a short content expiration, the browser will retrieve it again. So set your content expirations on static file folders to be safe.

Comment: thanks.  i set content expiration to 1 day on my Content and Scripts folder but when i reload the site, YSlow is still giving me an F on Add Expiry Headers.  Any thoughts ??

Comment: @ooo If I recall, YSlow wants the experation to be very long in the future (I think 1 year).

Answer (score 0):

A browser has no idea what content is 'static' or not; it literally has no way of knowing, and yslow is only guessing, most likely. It's probably guessing correctly... but having incorrect Expires values by default in the web server could cause browsers to cache dynamic content that you do not want them caching at all.

That's why it's not set like that by default.